# Fatal error: runtime:out of memory during install of geth

Tags: blockchain, go-ethereum

```
# make geth
build/env.sh go run build/ci.go install ./cmd/geth
>>>/usr/lib/golang/bin/go install -ldflags -X main.gitCommit=   -v
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/dashboard
#  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/dashboard
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
util.go:45: exit status 2
exit status 1
make: ***[geth] Error 1


System info:
Centos7.2
cpu 1G 1core
```

I wonder what is the requirement of the machine to install geth. Or something wrong when I installing the geth?

Comment: I don't know for installation, but to run it on mainnet, you need at least 3 to 4 Gb of ram.